# Up to date Tabbed Navigation

Tags: android, tabs, android-navigation

I can't seem to find an up to date resource on how to do a tabbed navigation bar in android. Every tutorial suggests using ActionBar and Tab in which everything seems to be deprecated. Does anyone know the current way of implementing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your primary options are:

- [Use `TabLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) from the Android Design Support Library, with or without [a `ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html); or
- Use a `ViewPager` and your favorite other tab solution for it, whether that be `PagerTabStrip` or [any number of third-party tab implementations](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/111); or
- [Use `FragmentTabHost`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html)

Comment: Android's APIs are a mess. :-(